# best way to use context in fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-context

i m using fragments in my application. i created one Parent Class called BaseFragment and all other fragment extends this Basefrgment below is the snippet of this Basefragment

**BaseFragment.java**

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    public MainActivity activity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (activity == null && context instanceof  MainActivity) {
            activity = (MainActivity) context;
        }
    }
}


public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, FragmentDetail last) {

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    boolean push = true;
    if (Validator.isNotNull(last)) {
        push = false;
    }
    /*if(Validator.isNull(last)){
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right);
    }else{
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
    }*/
    transaction.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());
    if (Validator.isNull(last) && preferences.getFragmentStack().size() > 0) {
        last = preferences.getFragmentStack().lastElement();
    }
    if (Validator.isNotNull(last)) {
        Fragment f = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(last.className);
        if (Validator.isNotNull(f)) {
            f.onPause();
            transaction.remove(f);
        }
    }
    last = new FragmentDetail(fragment.getClass().getName(), getTitle().toString(), preferences.isBack());
    if (preferences.isBack() || preferences.getFragmentStack().size() == 0) {
        if (push) {
            preferences.getFragmentStack().push(last);
        }
    } else {
        while (preferences.getFragmentStack().size() > 1) {
            preferences.getFragmentStack().pop();
        }
        if (!preferences.getFragmentStack().lastElement().className.equals(last.className)) {
            preferences.getFragmentStack().push(last);
        }
    }
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    changeNavigationIcon();
```

//        HWUtil.showToast(this, fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() + "");
    }

and in all other fragment i m using activity as a context,my question is whether it is bad way to access context in this way or whether it creates memory leak.or any other approach for accessing context..any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you are storing the `context` is really optimal as with that you will be able to use it within each of your sub fragment instances. Because `MainActivity` is an instance variable in your fragment, it will be garbage collected when your fragment gets destroyed. And if I'm not mistaken about Activity-Fragment lifecycle, when your activity gets rotated, new fragments will be created and the older fragment instances will get destroyed. So, we're good there too. However, you need to be careful with your context variable declaration:

```
public MainActivity activity;
```

This makes it accessible from anywhere. Any class can call something like `context = fragIns.activity` and save it there. This will be really bad for you because now it holds a reference to that context variable. Now, when your fragment is no longer needed it will not be garbage collected because some other class is holding a reference to one of its variable. You'd find yourself in "memory leak town".

Make sure you hold this variable dearly and its reference is not passed to other classes. Since, its in a super class, you may define it as:

```
protected MainActivity activity;
```

This should do the job.

Comment: @ Shaishav you are absolutealy right ..can u please give one more solution on how to access this context in Adapter class

Comment: You can pass the reference to your adapter instance by simply passing it `activity` variable. Just make sure the `adapter` instance itself is declared in your fragment only. We don't want the `activity` instance to be given to any class that may not get destroyed with our fragment :)

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to use getActivity() function inside fragment to access context,
because it will return the instance of the activity  on which fragment is attached.

Comment: but many times i faced null pointer exception as fragment is detached from activity

Comment: use getActivity().getApplicationContext() function and saved its instance as static so , that it could not be null when the fragment is detached from activity, and also first check the instance is null or not then only perform your operations

Comment: what if accidentially it becomes null as static variables are not recommanded

Comment: @GokulKumar Don't save anything `context` in static fields as it makes your app susceptible to memory leaks.

Comment: @Shaishav so what is the best way to achive this please suggest

Answer (score 1):

using `getActivity()` is easy and quick way to get parent activity's context but problem comes when that fragment is detached.

So using it like this inside fragment , imo, will suffice the need of doing it better way....

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {        
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mContext=activity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid memory problems it's recommended that whenever you use `onAttach(Context context)` you should use `onDetach()` as well:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (activity == null && context instanceof  MainActivity) {
        activity = (MainActivity) context;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    this.activity = null;
    super.onDetach();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My way:

```
public class AppManager extends Application {


    private static AppManager mApp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mApp = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mApp.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

so, anyone wants to get a `Context`, just using the `AppManager.getContext()`, except starting a `Activity`. It is very simple.

In your way,  if the activity restarted, the fragment will automatically create again. In you dont' handle the action of Activty restarted, it is posssible that the Activity have two same Fragment, and one who automatically creating didn't call `OnAttch()`, will causing `NullPointerException`.

My solution:

```
public abstract class BaseTabActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @CallSuper
    protected void initTabs(boolean isRestarted) {
        if (isRestarted) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            if (manager.getFragments() == null)
                return;
            Stream.of(manager.getFragments())
                    .forEach((fragment) -> {
                        if (fragment != null)
                            transaction.remove(fragment);
                    });
            transaction.commit();
            manager.executePendingTransactions();
        }
    }

    public FragmentTransaction getSlideAnimTransaction() {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_from_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
        return transaction;
    }

}
```

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya but as this is static variable may be it becomes null

Comment: @ Yakami i am not able to understand what you are trying say

Comment: @HardikMehta Sorry.....My english is bad.....  I just want to say that in your way, the variable ``MainActivity`` will be null in Activtiy restart in some cases. hope you can understand what I say....._(:3」∠)_ very sorry for my english.(´；ω；`)

Comment: @ Yakmi actually i am not able to understand the case that you are trying to say

Comment: @HardikMehta If a fragement  programmatically replaces a view to display in screen, when  the Activity restart ( rotating screen.etc), the fragment will automatically create himself again before our code. Therefore, if we don't handle the action, we will get two same fragments after the activity restarted.

Comment: @Yakmi i have to design it only for potrait mode

Comment: @HardikMehta Oh, it's a very bad way to avoid the problem, because if device has a low available memory,, and your activity is invisible, the system maybe recovery the memory of your activity. Therefore, when we go back, the activity will restart.

Comment: @Yakmi Yes very often I start the app it restart the activity so what I have to do please give suggestion,my requirement is only for potrait mode

Comment: @HardikMehta my solution is the code of second segment, A Activity  extends `BaseTabActivity` just when Activity run `onCreate(Bundle savedIntanceBundle)`, call the `initTabs(savedInstanceBundle)` in the ``onCreate``, it will clear the stack of fragment, avoiding the problem. It's not the best way, but very simple :)

Comment: @ Yakmi I will post logic for replacing fragment and it is controlled from main activity and all fragment in application extend from this base fragment

Comment: @ Yakmi i posted method for replacing fragments