# What is the best place to call getContext()?

Tags: android

I was reading fragment documentation and found this:

> Caution: If you need a Context object within your Fragment, you can call getContext(). However, be careful to call getContext() only when the fragment is attached to an activity. When the fragment isn't attached yet or was detached during the end of its lifecycle, getContext() returns null

So my question is what is the best place to call getContext() inside the fragment. Like i can call it in onCreateView, or onCreate() or onAttach() on any other place.

I am asking this because recently I got a crash of null pointer using getContext in my fragment. So I thought I should create a global Context object and access it inside the fragment. But then I came across this text from official documentation so I am a bit confused what would be the best place to initialize this Context object.

Comment: saving a global instance of context is **wrong**. You can avoid crashes by checking whether `getContext()` returns null or not. As said in the documentation, the context has a value after the fragment is attached. So, after `onAttach()` is called. Btw, don't store it inside your fragment, it can lead to other crashes.

Comment: If your fragment is part of an activity class, then you can use getApplicationContext(); however, due the lack of code example of your problem its harder to provide you with a feasible solution.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti then if context is null how to handle that particular code like for instance i have to call Toast then how should i get context

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti I got it saving the context is wrong but why is this question getting downvoted when most of the people are suggesting wrong answers. Shouldn't this be upvoted so that most of us can prevent ourselves from same error we all do?

Comment: I always hated when someone is affirming something but not entering in details. If you are afraid of memory leaks, then tell the people, that to be sure that the object is garbage collected. Otherwise is somehow funny to say something that you just heard.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti is there anything like weak reference

Comment: another post about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800839/best-way-to-use-context-in-fragment

Comment: @SrishtiMittal I did not downvote your question, in fact, I also answered it. Probably it's downvoted because it's already asked and answered.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends what you need that `Context` for. Sometimes it's just fine to call `getApplicationContext()`, in other cases it may be needed to use what you are given in `onAttach()` or call `getActivity()` if you are in `Fragment` code. Some are also providing own `Application` subclass, exposing static method like `getAppContext()`.

In any case, **AVOID** saving the context as it may lead to memory leak. Get it dynamically **when needed** only.

Answer (score 1):

As a lot of wrong answers are given, I'll provide what's the best way to handle context inside fragments.

The best solution is checking if the context has a value whenever you need it.
You can do it by wrapping the code in which you access the fragment in 2 ways:

```
if (getContext() != null) { /* code here */ }
```

or, as stated in the documentation there's this method:

```
isAdded()
```

which: "Return true if the fragment is currently added to its activity." [-reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#isAdded())

Again: please **AVOID** saving the context in a local fragment's variable.

Comment: If you take care that the field is garbage collected , and is not used outside of the Fragment, it has nothing wrong to do with it. It is just a simple field in a class, so you don't need to reinvent the Wheel, the only issue was to get it in a right place, to not have null.

Comment: the problem occurs when the fragment gets detached. You still have a reference to a context which you shouldn't have.

Comment: For this exist event onDetach() , and you can easily manage the instance. Like i said It is not wrong , you just should be aware of what you are doing. And forcing detaching is a very specific thing and the same you should know what you are doing.

Comment: I don't see any answer here with that part too. I agree with you, but why should I need another variable when I can access it with the `getContext()`?

Comment: In case that you have the situation when you force the onDetach(), which normaly is on destroyng the fragment, so the GC takes care of all variables it is no difference. But in the case you use as normal fragments with normal behaviour, you get rid of a lot of calls of null checking, because you cannot use getContext() without null check. Check here the lifecycle of a fragment https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ztBy.png where everything is very clear what and when to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this in your fragment.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // After this point the context is initialized.
    context=activity;
}
```

NOTE: I don't really get it why it is so not liked this answer.
First af all, depending on the version of android(which was not mentioned), of course the OnAttach is deprecated, it has to be checked.
Next:
I think that if you need cobntext somewhere, you can make a private or protected variable in Fragment, so the context is destroyed when it is garbage collected.
protected MainActivity activity;

Make sure you hold this variable dearly and its reference is not passed to other classes.

This should do the job.

Comment: that looks really worng, even if you can do it

Comment: @LucaNicoletti even if you're right. try to be kind.

Comment: If you take care that the context is garbage collected, it has nothing wrong in that, using a private field

Comment: Defining context variable as static is wrong, if you define context as private, non static variable assigning context inside onAttach() is perfectly fine. After onDestroy context will be garbage collected

Answer (score -3):

You can implement your logic like this :

```
private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mContext = context;
}
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    mContext = null;
    super.onDetach();
}
```

When you required to use context,

```
if(mContext != null) {
   //Add your logic here
}
```

Comment: OMG. Saving the context is WRONG. Stop suggesting it.

Comment: It is not wrong , you just should be aware of what you are doing. Otherwise it will be wrong to use private fields of objects in general.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti We just need to manage the things on the right way.

Comment: Add proper reason in comment if you are downvoting.